# read_csv using uncommon delimiters

Tags: csv, pandas

I have a csv file that uses þ as a quote, and the paragraph symbol as the comma-separated value.

Using the subclass csv.Dialect isn't working. Pandas isn't interpreting the þ value as a string.

Any ideas?

```
# This works when the delimiters are more standard (; ")
# But really trying to make it work with the ASCII chars commented out below

import csv

f = open('./data/Test_Quote_SemiColon.dat')

class my_dialect(csv.Dialect):
    lineterminator = '\n'
    delimiter = ';'  # ASCII: 020
    quotechar = '"'  # ASCII: 254

reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=my_dialect, quoting=1)

for line in reader:
    print line
```

Here is the (quote and semi-colon) data:

"BEGID";"ENDID";"Name";"To";"From";"CC";"BCC"
"ABC_001";"ABC_004";"Smith, John";"Doe, John";"Roe, Jane";"";""
"ABC_005";"ABC_007";"Smith, John";"Doe, John";"";"";""
"ABC_008";"ABC_012";"Doe, John";"Doe, John";"Smith, John";"";""

Comment: Can you give a small example of you data (past a part of your csv file, or something that looks like it and replicates the problem), as well as the code you used to read it with pandas.

Comment: What encoding is used on the csv? Have you tried change the encoding? Do you know the ASCII codes of those symbols, so you can do sep ='something' and quote = 'something'?

Answer (score 0):

I found both the literal and the `chr(254)` worked to parse this. Does this seem right?

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> txt = '''þBEGIDþþENDIDþþNameþþToþþFromþþCCþþBCCþ þABC_001þþaBC_004þþSmith, JohnþþDoe, JohnþRoe, Janeþþþþþ þABC_005þþaBC_007þþSmith, JohnþþDoe, Johnþþþþþþ þABC_008þþaBC_012þþDoe, JohnþþDoe, JohnþSmith, Johnþþþþþ'''
>>> reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(txt), delimiter=',', quotechar=chr(254))
>>> for line in reader: 
...     for entry in line:
...         print unicode(entry, 'utf8')
... 
þBEGIDþþENDIDþþNameþþToþþFromþþCCþþBCCþ þABC_001þþaBC_004þþSmith
 JohnþþDoe
 JohnþRoe
 Janeþþþþþ þABC_005þþaBC_007þþSmith
 JohnþþDoe
 Johnþþþþþþ þABC_008þþaBC_012þþDoe
 JohnþþDoe
 JohnþSmith
 Johnþþþþþ
```

---

`txt` echoes like:

```
>>> txt
'\xc3\xbeBEGID\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeENDID\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeName\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeTo\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeFrom\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeCC\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeBCC\xc3\xbe \xc3\xbeABC_001\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeaBC_004\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeSmith, John\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeDoe, John\xc3\xbeRoe, Jane\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe \xc3\xbeABC_005\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeaBC_007\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeSmith, John\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeDoe, John\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe \xc3\xbeABC_008\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeaBC_012\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeDoe, John\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbeDoe, John\xc3\xbeSmith, John\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe\xc3\xbe'
```

Comment: Just FYI, using iPython Notebook 2.2, Python 2.7.6
I'm seeing an error for StringIO.  What is the import?

Comment: Close - but not quite it. I think it needs a lineterminator value.

It should look like this (without the single quotes):

['BEGID', 'ENDID', 'Name', 'To', 'From', 'CC', 'BCC']
['ABC_001', 'ABC_004', 'Smith, John', 'Doe, John', 'Roe, Jane', '', '']
['ABC_005', 'ABC_007', 'Smith, John', 'Doe, John', '', '', '']
['ABC_008', 'ABC_012', 'Doe, John', 'Doe, John', 'Smith, John', '', '']